# Hero animation based on picture frames in jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a hero (Reptile from MK) to move backwards, forwards, duck, etc... by key events. But when I try to iterate over certain amount of pictures to do the movement, it kinda bugs :S is there any other good approach? or what am I doing wrong?

All the movement is kinda bugged :/ is there a way to make it move smoothly? The pictures aren't working so good either, sometimes skips a few pictures or walks with the very same picture for over a few seconds.

Here's my code, I will add all in the same HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #reptile_wrapper {
            position:relative;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="reptile_wrapper">
        <img src="img/0.png"/>
    </div>

    <script>

        /* Preload all the images and gifs */
        var img_list, img_count, base_str, img_obj, i, prefix_str, suffix_img_str, suffix_gif_str;

        img_list   = [ 'd01', 'd02'];
        gif_list = ['reptile_walk_forward', 'reptile_walk_backward', 'reptile_idle'];
        prefix_str = 'img/';
        suffix_img_str = '.png';
        suffix_gif_str = '.gif';

        img_count  = img_list.length;
        for ( i = 0; i < img_count; i++ ) {
          base_str    = img_list[ i ];
          img_obj     = new Image();
          img_obj.src = prefix_str + base_str + suffix_img_str;
        }

        gif_count  = gif_list.length;
        for ( i = 0; i < gif_count; i++ ) {
          base_str    = gif_list[ i ];
          img_obj     = new Image();
          img_obj.src = prefix_str + base_str + suffix_gif_str;
        }
        /* End of preloading images and gifs */

        var duckImages = ["d01", "d02"];
        var posx = 10;

        reptileIdleAnimation();

        $('body').keydown(function(event) {
            switch(event.which) {
                // D
                case 68:                    
                    posx += 5;
                    $("#reptile_wrapper img").attr('src', 'img/reptile_walk_forward.gif')
                        .parent().css({left: posx+'px'});                   
                break;
                // A    
                case 65:
                    posx -= 5;
                    $("#reptile_wrapper img").attr('src', 'img/reptile_walk_backward.gif')
                        .parent().css({left: posx+'px'});   
                break;
                // S
                case 83:
                    $.each(duckImages, function( index, value ) {
                        var myAnim = setInterval(function(){
                            $("#reptile_wrapper img").attr('src', 'img/' + value + '.png')
                                .parent().css({"top": "40px"});
                            clearInterval(myAnim);
                        }, 200);
                    });
                break;

                default:
                    reptileIdleAnimation();
                break;
            }


        })
        .keyup(function() {
            reptileIdleAnimation();
        });

        function reptileIdleAnimation() {
            $("#reptile_wrapper img").attr('src', 'img/reptile_idle.gif');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I recommend is to preload all your images.

```
 var img_list, img_count, base_str, img_obj, i, prefix_str, suffix_str;

 img_list   = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];
 prefix_str = 'http://myserver.com/images/';
 suffix_str = '.png';

 img_count  = img_list.length;
 for ( i = 0; i < img_count; i++ ) {
   base_str    = img_list[ i ];
   img_obj     = new Image();
   img_obj.src = prefix_str + base_str + suffix_str;
 }
```

Of course you will need to replace the img_list, prefix_str, and suffix_str with your own values.  Once the images are preloaded, any network latency would be removed, and your animation should be smoother.  Let me know if that isn't enough :)

Comment: Decided to make it directly with animated gifs, thing is that yea it works great, but the animations are choppy, why is that happening? is because of that? i mean i need to preload the animated gifs? Thanks for replying too :)

Comment: updated my code so you can see how it's going... but the animation is still getting choppy, is because i'm not using the img_obj.src ? :/

Comment: The preload code looks good.  If it is still choppy, it is probably due to other code.  If you post a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) I can probably fix it :)

Comment: Don't know why i couldn't make the background images work, but here it is jsfiddle.net/S8dj5/1 look what happens also if you press S+K (to block while ducking) and then release K, it does like a little jump passing the floor.

Comment: Btw, i've added and removed a lot of code because i was testing other stuff D: but you can modify and add yours there and see ^_^

Comment: I forked it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9A484/.  Seems to work pretty well.  Notice the use of a jqueryMap cache and the use of a switch, among other changes.  Also, I used jQuery to bind handler.

Comment: Do you see the animation smoothly? i don't :((( you sure you've posted the latest one? i can't see the jqueryMap, or jQuery bind handler, looks like that's not the latest version

Comment: Ok, fixed - you were right - I forgot to press 'update'.  Now you should see the changes at http://jsfiddle.net/9A484/2/

Comment: But still not working the smooth movement :( i mean i see it as he's skiing T_T do you see it properly?

Comment: I could certainly make this animation work more smoothly, but that issue is a bigger undertaking.  It means adding frames and normalizing the display techniques.  Sorry I don't have time for that, but I hope the substantial work I did gives you a good foundation for fixing these issues.

Comment: Yeah i mean, your code rocks mate! :) nice way of organizing all the stuff! Going to tick it as resolved ^_^ and keep trying to find that bug. Thanks for all your time

Comment: @user3078876: Thanks!  I am glad you like code.  Our code standards are burned into my brain, so that is where some of the organization comes from :P